# PHPUnit: How to check that an array has an object with a specific attribute?

Tags: phpunit

Say we have the following array, `$myArray`, to check as per var_export:

```php
array (
  0 => AnObject::__set_state(array(
           'id' => 10,
           'name' => 'foo'
  )),
  1 => AnObject::__set_state(array(
           'id' => 23,
           'name' => 'bar'
  )),
  2 => AnObject::__set_state(array(
           'id' => 55,
           'name' => 'baz'
  )),
)
```

The assertion should pass if this array contains an `AnObject` which has a name of `'bar'`.

I know that if I knew the position of the `AnObject` value, I could use:

```php
$this->assertAttributeSame('bar', 'name', $myArray[1]);
```

Is there some way to use `$this->assertThat()`, or another type of contains to check the entire array and return true of one of the objects has the attribute that matches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such built-in assertion and I cannot think of any possibility to combine them to get the expected result.

What I recommend you - is to create a helper method that accepts an array and does the necessary check in a loop.

Other solution is to create completely new assertion just for this case, but I think it is an overkill for this task ;-)

Comment: Depends, if you need that check more often or the actual comparison is getting more and more complex: an own assertion is not that hard to integrate. Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on the answer provided by zerkms, below is how I approached this exact task:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue($this->assertArrayContainsSameObject($yourArray, $theObjectToCheck));
```

To check an array contains an object with the same attributes and values (i.e. not necessarily referencing the same instance):

```
private function assertArrayContainsSameObject($theArray, $theObject)
{
    foreach($theArray as $arrayItem) {
        if($arrayItem == $theObject) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

To check for the same reference, simply change `==` to `===`.

To solve the original poster's question:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Assert::assertTrue($this->assertArrayContainsSameObjectWithValue($yourArray, 'name', 'bar'));


private function assertArrayContainsSameObjectWithValue($theArray, $attribute, $value)
{
    foreach($theArray as $arrayItem) {
        if($arrayItem->$attribute == $value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```